# Which is the best mechanism to save emails and attachment while using kloudless

Tags: php, email, cloud, attachment, kloudless

We are fetching emails from GMAIL/OUTLOOK using [Kloudless](https://kloudless.com/) and now we need to share that emails with attachment in our own cloud applications so in this case which is the correct way to save emails and attachments.

1. should we save them in database(e.g. Mysql) and attachment we can save in the cloud e.g. in the AWS S3.
2. or we can save the emails as a file and attachments on AWS S3.

which is the correct way to save these kind of emails.